# How to replace if-Statement by using Optional/Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to replace the if statement by using Optional or similar lambda construct?
The idea is to having one statement without if.

```
private boolean check(@Nullable Result result) {
    if (result != null && result.getAnswers() != null) {
        return result.getAnswers().stream()
                .filter(a -> "a".equals(a.getId()))
                .findFirst()
                .map(q -> "xy".equals(q.getValue()))
                .orElse(false);
    }
    return false;
}

class Result {
  private List<MyAnswer> answers;
}

public class MyAnswer {
  private final String id;
  private final String value;
}
```

Comment: There is,a way, but I can’t see why you should want to. Your code is just fine as it is.

Comment: In `Result` I don’t think you should ever allow `answers` to be `null`. Set it to `Collections.emptyList()` if appropriate. It does not take up more space than `null` and will allow you to stream the collection without a null check first.

Comment: You could simply use `return result != null && result.getAnswers() != null && result.getAnswers().stream() …` Instead of `.map(q -> "xy".equals(q.getValue())) .orElse(false)`, you can use `.filter(q -> "xy".equals(q.getValue())) .isPresent()` but perhaps, your entire operation is actually meant to be `result.getAnswers().stream() .anyMatch(a -> "a".equals(a.getId()) && "xy".equals(a.getValue()))`

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked:

```
private boolean check(@Nullable Result result) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(result)
            .map(Result::getAnswers)
            .map(l -> l.stream()
                    .filter(a -> "a".equals(a.getId()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(q -> "xy".equals(q.getValue()))
                    .orElse(false))
            .orElse(false);
}
```

Comment: Why can `answers` be `null`? What does that mean? If it means semantically the same thing as an empty list, then why is `answers` ever null? Why isn't it initialized as `List.of()` and marked NonNull? Your question doesn't include these details, but excessive reliance on null chains is almost always a sign you're using `null` as a valid semantic state when you shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

`Optional<Result> maybeResult = Optional.ofNullable( result )` will give you an optional which is either present or not present depending on whether `result` was `null` or not.

Then, you can use `maybeResult.map( r -> r.getAnswers().stream()... )` or `maybeResult.ifPresent( r -> r.getAnswers().stream()... )`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
for example :

```
String job = ...; // some string value
String str = Optional.ofNullable(job)
    .map(n -> "Your job is : " + n)
    .orElse("I dont know what is your job");
```